# Logical Design Operation, A Simple Questions?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, computer-architecture, logic-gates, decoder

I'm so sorry if I ask my first question that so simple. My filed is Math and Computer science.  I self-study Digital Design.

> My challenge is how we can find the operation of the two following Diagram
>   ?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a truth table for each of the circuits?

Comment: What do you know about digital logic? Do you know how logic gates, decoders, and multiplexers work?

Comment: without truth table, is there any creative way @Samuel

Comment: @Gregd'Eon yeah, I know a bit for all of them. but I select some picture from my book to learn it as an example !

Comment: I'm not sure what "creative" way you're thinking of - most methods will be a lot more complicated than a truth table, and I don't know if you'll get much more understanding out of them.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon the way for find operation is using truth table ?

Comment: Are you looking for how to write the equations?

Comment: yes @Tut the truth table is simple and I can work it. I need learn how write equation for these example.

Comment: Since this looks like homework, can you show us some work? Can you write an equation for each output of each individual component? Once you work that out, work left-to-right and substitute the equation for the output of the previous stage for an input term in the next stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've done this the long way.

**The Truth Table**

The first step for learning what these circuits do is to create a truth table. Perhaps you already know how to do this, but didn't know it was the first step, we'll go over it in any case. I'll work out the first example circuit.

Make columns for each of your inputs and outputs. Sometimes it's easier to also make columns for intermediate values, just to help you determine the final outputs. You have A, B, and C as inputs, the output of the mux is not labeled, but it is the output for this circuit.

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| A | B | C | Out |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

Now fill out the possible inputs. You'll only want to do this for truth tables with fewer than four or five inputs, they get too big otherwise. I always start with the rightmost input and alternate between writing one 0 and one 1 while filling out the rows. There are three inputs, so that means there are eight possible permutations (2^3). For the next input to the right you fill in by alternate between writing two 0's and two 1's while filling out the rows. The final input by alternate between writing four 0's and four 1's while filling out the rows. That's just how I used to do it; find your own best way. The rows are just counting up in binary.

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| A | B | C | Out |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 0 | 0 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+        
| 0 | 0 | 1 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 0 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 1 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 0 | 0 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 0 | 1 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 1 | 0 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |     |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

Now fill it in with the obvious stuff first. For instance, since A is controlling the mux, anytime its equal to 1, the output is simply NOT B. That takes care of the bottom half of the table.

For the other half, when A is 0, the output is simply B AND C.

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| A | B | C | Out |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  0  |
+---+---+---+-----+        
| 0 | 0 | 1 |  0  |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 0 |  0  |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 1 |  1  |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 0 | 0 |  1  |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 0 | 1 |  1  |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 1 | 0 |  0  |
+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  0  |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

**The Equation**

By looking at it piecewise like that, what you're really doing is translating the circuit into sentences, those sentences can then be described with boolean equations.

The sentences were:

If A, then the output is NOT B.

If NOT A, then the output is B AND C.

In terms of the output this means that the output is true when either B AND C is true and NOT A is true ***or*** A is true and NOT B is true.

Thus the equation is Output = (~A & (B & C)) | (A & ~B).

That method may be too difficult for you at first. The long way for the equation is to write out the equation for each row of the truth table and reduce the logic with boolean algebra. You should do that *once*, then learn how to draw a [karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and write the equation from the reduced logic produced by that.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get to an equation for any problem like this will be to write out a truth table and then use a K-Map to get an and-or equation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

First problem:

Truth Table

\$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
A&B&C&Out\\
\hline
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
\end{array}\$

K-Map

\$\begin{array}{c|c} 
_{AB}\diagdown^C&0\quad 1\\
\hline
00&0\quad 0\\
01&0\quad\boxed 1\\
11&0\quad 0\\
10&\boxed{1\quad 1}\\
\end{array}\$

\$
OUT =  A\overline B+\overline ABC 
\$

Comment: Would you please solve it and attach picture ?

Comment: Updated with solution to first problem, you should try the second one.

Comment: I try more and more but couldent. please learn me with the second one. this is two different diagram. +1.

Comment: Both problems have the same truth table, and the same answer. They are equivalent circuits.

Answer (score 1):

**Deriving Logical Expressions**
Deriving a logical expression from a given logical circuit involves tracing the path from input to output and writing intermediate logical expressions along the path. The process is illustrated in the following figure.
[image]

Having in mind these  simple gates:
[image]

One possible multiplexer implementation is:
[image]

One possible decoder implementation is:
[image]>

**So depending on the value (1,0) of your input signals, A, B, C and using the truth tables you can easily determine the output.**